# Plesk is blocked on change the domain prefix

Tags: apache, centos, plesk

I have a Plesk 12.0.18 on Centos Server. All subscriptions works fine, but one subscription have a domain with this problem.

When i change the domain prefix to "www.mydomain.com" or to "mydomain.com", this still stuck to "Waiting...".

When this happens, the rest of the server still works fine, but will not let me make any changes to the rest of subscriptions.

I try to edit the apache vhosts, but this looks fine.

Please I need a help.

Comment: I can only recommend to create a request to support team to do in-depth investigation to find the reason and to fix it. https://www.odin.com/support/request/ .
If there’s no free support in your case, you can order Plesk per-incident support at http://www.odin.com/support/buy-support/ Support team will contact you as soon as purchase is processed, and they will do the best to resolve it.
If it is found that your problem was caused by product bug w/o available solution or workaround from Parallels, then your purchase will be re-funded.

Comment: ok thx. i'm trying with talk.plesk.com

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the plesk databases and due to that your process is getting stuck. I will suggest you please check your panel error logs file OR ask your system admin to check this.

Comment: I can see this in error_log:

6910#0: *12727 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: **.**.***.***, server: , request: "GET /admin/backup/list HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/sw-engine.sock", host: "**.**.***.***:****", referrer: "https://**.**.***.***:****/admin/server/tools"